# как отправить headers на localhost Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

В доках нужно ставить полный путь на сайт но так же не найдет:

```php
$response = Http::withToken($token)->post('http://localhost/api/auth/logout');
```

а так он не знает сайт

```php
$response = Http::withToken($token)->post('api/auth/logout');
```

Comment: а в env или конфиге доменное имя нигде не фиксируется?

Comment: Это отправка запроса с сервера?

Comment: @lezhni да это я тест пишу чтобы с теста обратится на текущий домен сейчас он локалный но если его залить на хостинг то  будет же другой домен, просто а как мне проверить тест на локалке?

Comment: @ProgRamm или формировать урл, беря из конфига домен (`APP_URL`), либо вариант проще - присваивать имена роутам и обращаться как  `Http::withToken($token)->post(route('name'));`

Comment: А зачем так делать? чем $this->get(...) $this->post()... не устроил? Http необходим для обращения к внешним ресурсам, а не к себе (учитывая код который приведён), особенно при написании тестов

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov потому что мне нужно проверить глобально с передачей токена а чтобы передать токен в доках нашел Http::withToken($token) то есть заголовки

Comment: эм, а это чем не подходит?? $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"])->post(....) или так: $this->post(route('my_path'), [
            'world' => 'hello'
        ], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov что так можно было вот только недавно в коментах тут узнал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = $this->post('api/auth/logout', 
            ['token_id' => $dataToken->id], 
            ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $dataToken->token]
        );
```